# Calling a (404) inexisting page Vs blank page. Which one consumes less resources?

Tags: c#, php, webclient

Recently I've made an application in which I've made a stupid mistake by hard cording the url I want to post data to instead of using a proxy such as no-ip.

In short words, this app is sending requests regularly to my site which ended up in consuming lots of resources to my site. The request are sent to a PHP page which doesn't exist on my site:

```
 http://www.example.com/non-existing-page.php
```

I suspect that it's impossible to prevent the distributed app from sending requests to my site without changing the url of my website.

The thing is that I cannot change the url and transfer my site to different URL, So what I need to know now is what should I do in order to make this stupid mistake less resource consuming.

1- Keep things as it is

or

2- Creating a blank php with the name of the called script..

**Here is the short question:**
When I call a page on a remote server through WebClient, which thing consume more server resources, calling a blank php page or calling an inexisting php page..

Thanks in advance

Comment: either way you're using up server time, but at least the non-existent page won't have to fire up the PHP subsystem, since the webserver can reject the request when it's checking if "foo.php" actually exists or not.

Comment: You should be asking which one gives a meaningful response to the client application.... using a 301 redirect might be a better solution

Comment: Yeah! I know either way is not a solution.. but you mean that calling an non-existing page will be less resource consuming. am I right? @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general broad sense whether the 404 page will be displayed or not depends on the browser.

IE doesn't show a custom 404 page unless it's larger than 512 bytes.
See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/08/19/http-error-pages-in-internet-explorer.aspx)
Same deal with chrome too.

If you do want to put a custom 404 page make sure you include a favicon in it. Otherwise it leads to really long loading times. Discussed at length [here](http://internetfolks.com/dastardly-favicon-ico-found-error/)